# How to generate HTML table by looping through object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have the following object:

`var obj = {
        key1: 'value1',
        key2: 'value2',
        key3: 'value3'
    }`

```js
var obj = {
     key1: 'value1',
     key2: 'value2',
     key3: 'value3'
    }
    
    $('#myTable thead tr').append('<th>Key Column</th>');
    $('#myTable thead tr').append('<th>Value Column</th>');
    var markup = '';
    for (var i in obj) {
     markup = "<tr><td>" + i + "</td></td><td>" + obj[i] + "</td></tr>";
     $("#myTable tbody #first-col").append(markup);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
       <thead>
          <tr>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr id="first-col">
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

I want to create a table by looping the object.
But I am getting like this:

```
+-------------+--------------+
| Key Column  | Value Column |
+-------------+--------------+
| key1 value1 |              |
+-------------+--------------+
| key2 value2 |              |
+-------------+--------------+
| And so on.. |              |
+-------------+--------------+
```

**Kindly guide me how to perform it correctly. Or if it is better to generate the whole table again using jQuery, please let me know how to do it? Thanks**

Comment: You are generating rows / `<tr>`s, but then instead of appending them to `tbody`, you're appending them to the first row...

Comment: To add on to Chris's comment, you also have one extra ```</td>``` after the key column.

Comment: *"But I am getting like this"* - You're looking at the wrong output.  Don't only examine the final rendered result.  Your code is building HTML.  Look at *the resulting HTML it builds*.  Does it look correct to you?  Why not?  What's wrong with it?  If the resulting HTML string looks correct to you then you need some tutorials/guidance on how to create tables in HTML.  If it doesn't look correct to you then it gives you all of the information you need to debug your code.

Comment: ` $("#myTable tbody #first-col").append(markup);` your selector is not correct like @ChrisG said, use this `$("#myTable tbody").append(markup);`

Comment: as @dotoconnor said, `markup = "<tr><td>" + i + "</td></td><td>" + obj[i] + "</td></tr>";` there is 1 extra closing tag `</td>`, u can use this `<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + obj[i] + "</td></tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$("#myTable tbody #first-col").append(markup);
```

To this:

```
$("#myTable tbody").append(markup);
```

Like so:

```
var obj = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    key3: 'value3'
}

$(function() {  
  $('#myTable thead tr').append('<th>Key Column</th>');
  $('#myTable thead tr').append('<th>Value Column</th>');
  var markup = '';
  for (var i in obj) {
    markup = "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + obj[i] + "</td></tr>";
    $("#myTable tbody").append(markup);
  }
});
```

I also removed an extra `</td>` as mentioned in the comments.

Then it works.  Codepen: https://codepen.io/haukurhaf/pen/jQWNGe

Comment: Thanks man. It does solved the issue.